# javascript Fibonacci sequence return undefined

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I was trying to write a small function return Fibonacci sequence. Here is my code:

```js
function fib2(n) {
  let fib = [];
  fib[0] = 1;
  fib[1] = 1;
  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
  }
  return fib[i];
}

console.log(fib2(6));
```

but the result is undefined. I guess it's because of some closure issue but I am not sure about why. Could someone explain what happened? Thank you

Comment: Accessing the `i = n` index which doesn't exist.  The last increment reaches to `n`.

Comment: you are going outside of the array.

Comment: When `i` equals `5`, your loop condition increases it to `6` *after* the loop execution. After the loop ends, `i` now equals `6`. `fib[6]` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the for loop, variable i has value n, so fib[i] is out of the array.

```js
function fib2(n) {
  let fib = [];
  fib[0] = 1;
  fib[1] = 1;
  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
  }
  return fib[n-1];
}

console.log(fib2(6));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's right. Further question, can I just return fib[i]? I try to do return fib[i] but it's still undefined.

Comment: You could do i-- before the return statement, so it takes value n-1, but it would be the same as the code I posted. Or f you want fib[i] to be defined, you could do fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1] after the for loop too.

Answer (score 1):

```
function fib2(n) {
    let fib = [];
    fib[0] = 1;
    fib[1] = 1;
    for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        fib[i] = fib[i-2] + fib[i-1];
    }
    return fib;
}
console.log(fib2(6));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
(6) [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

**In addition**

if I were you, I am trying to change the name of the function and the name of the variable in the function for distinguishing.

```
function fib(n) {
  let arr = [];
  arr[0] = 1;
  arr[1] = 1;
  for(let i = 2; i < n; i++){
    arr[i] = arr[i-2] + arr[i-1];
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(fib(6));
```

If you want to get the last element of the sequence,

```
function lastFib(n){
  let prev = 1;
  let now = 1;
  let temp = 0;
  for(let i = 2; i < n; i++){
    temp = now;
    now = prev + now;
    prev = temp;
  }
  return now;
}
console.log(lastFib(6));
```